# On the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \cos(x \log(n) + a) $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, divergent-series, trigonometric-series

Is the following series ‘summable’ in the sense that it may be divergent but we can attach a meaning to it?

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \cos(x \log(n) + a) = (\text{reg}) \quad \frac{\zeta'(1/2 + ia + ix)}{\zeta(1/2 + ia + ix)} + \frac{\zeta'(1/2 - ia - ix)}{\zeta(1/2 - ia - ix)}.
> $$

If we assume that this is correct, then what would be the limit as $ x \to \infty $?

This series was obtained simply by setting $ s = 1/2 + ix $ inside the power series
$$
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Lambda(n) n^{-s}.
$$
Also, for large $ x $, this can be applied to the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\sqrt{n}} {J_{0}}(x \log(n)).
$$

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i know the series is divergent... ETHAN however my question is if i can truncate it or give a 'sum' to this series for every 'x'